# Call function to change GUI outside of OnGUI() in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a project and part of the requirements is that the simulation draws a rectangle that changes color based on certain flags/events that occur in the simulation. This is a driving simulation with stoplights so events may include stoplight colour changes, control input, etc. Here's the code I have right now.

```
private static Rect rectangle = new Rect(0,0,50,50);

private static Texture2D _staticRectTexture;
private static GUIStyle _staticRectStyle;

public static void GUIDrawRect(Color color )
{
    if( _staticRectTexture == null )
    {
        _staticRectTexture = new Texture2D( 1, 1 );
    }

    if( _staticRectStyle == null )
    {
        _staticRectStyle = new GUIStyle();
    }

    _staticRectTexture.SetPixel( 0, 0, color );
    _staticRectTexture.Apply();

    _staticRectStyle.normal.background = _staticRectTexture;

    GUI.Box( rectangle, GUIContent.none, _staticRectStyle );
}

public void OnGUI() {
    GUIDrawRect (Color.blue);

}
```

Now, essentially the problem is that this method can only be called in the `OnGUI()` method. This method needs to be able to be called from any class/method. For example, when my `ChangeLight()` method (changes stoplight) is called I want to be able to call `GUIDrawRect(Color color)` inside of it to change the rectangle.

The rectangle has to be on the GUI because I am only going to be drawing it to the master computer (not the multiple projectors rendering the scene) and also because a photo-diode is being used to detect changes in color from this rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a public variable, property or a method to change the color.

```
public Color slColor;

public static void GUIDrawRect(Color color) {
  // draw rect
}

public void OnGUI() {
  GUIDrawRect(slColor);
}
```

Now you can simply set the variable `slColor` to the desired color from any script or method.